# Does ZF have a filter for nl2br?

Tags: zend-framework, nl2br, zend-filter

Does Zend Framework have a nl2br filter?  I can't see it - am I just missing it?

I imagine I could do the same thing with PregReplace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have an existing PHP function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) it really begs the question: "do we really need to wrap a ZF filter class around a function?"

There are a few filters that actually do that.

In terms of forms for injecting a filter (and maybe other cases) I would say yes or when we need some more flexibility with additional options; basically extending the PHP function. I don't really see a need for this particular function and you should be fine to simply use PHP out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

No, **Zend Framework** dos't have `nl2br` filter. If you want to use it then you should put it in your code where you want.

You can use any other methods also similar to that for achieving this.